# How to mention static files in .js file for a django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, static, web-frontend

I am facing an issue for mentioning one of the files in my django project for a `.js` file

One of the lines in main.js reads

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("{% static '/static/sw.js' %}")
```

but while running the project it says `Not Found: /sw.js`

This is the directory structure -

[image]

How should I mention the `sw.js` file in my `main.js` file to avoid **fileNotFound error**?

Added to `settings.py` -

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
```

`urls.py` includes

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('/push_v1/', push_v1),
    path('/subscription/', subscription),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Complete error -
[image]

Find the code on Github for reference [Code Link](https://github.com/Viking-Programmer/Django-Webpush)

Comment: have you tried, `{% static 'fbpush/static/sw.js' %}` ?

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work ! Also, I have included `{% load static %}` in both `sw.js` and `main.js` at 1st line. Do I need to add anything else ?

Comment: `{% load static %}` supposed to be added in HTML files, not js files

Comment: TRy `{% static 'sw.js' %}` or `{% static '/sw.js' %}`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have already tried that, it doesn't work ! Same error : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your setting.py file set the location for your static files

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and than in you template first load the static and than set the script file n template itself.

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'sw.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response! I tried this but doesn't seem to be working. For reference, I have added the code on github: [code link](https://github.com/Viking-Programmer/Django-Webpush)

Comment: get rid of the extra static after the comma from STATICDIR_FILE and in you template script tag you could do this directly {% static 'sw.js' %} in you src

Comment: I did the suggested change .. Seems that I am still missing on something. I have committed the changes to the repository. It will be a great help if you could please have a look at it (especially `index.html` header section and line 128 of `main.js`) [repo link](https://github.com/Viking-Programmer/Django-Webpush)

Comment: are non of the static file being loaded or is it only the js file?

Comment: if that is the case than try running this command python manage.py collectstatic cause the code looks fine.

Comment: I see this error - `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\static'`

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') add this file in setting and then run the command